# Получить id из ссылки

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как вытащить Id из следующего линка:

```
https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183364240.json
```

Делал по аналогу с youtube:

```
else if (input.contains("vimeo")) {
            vimeoUrl = "https://www.vimeo.com/";
            String vimeoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(vimeoId)) {
                String[] str = input.split("/");
                vimeoId = str[str.length - 1];
                vimeoUrl = "https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video" + uri.getPath();
                Log.d("vimeoUrl", vimeoUrl + " " + controlList.get(23).getImageUploads().size());
                return vimeoUrl;
```

Без понятия как объявить vimeoId, так как в ссылке показанной выше парамет v отсутствует.

Answer (score 4):

Вытаскивайте, например, строку от последнего слэша до последней точки

```
String url = "https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183364240.json";
String id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.lastIndexOf(".");
```

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию, но подчеркивает красным цветом subString, мол не могу реализовать данный метод.

Comment: @VadimMorozov а так? url.toString().subString(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.lastIndexOf(".");

Comment: @tCode к сожалению также

Comment: @VadimMorozov, попробуйте с малькой буквой